# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:localhost

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc

создал проект в Idea и БД на MySQL, вроде все подключик как положено, mysql connector импортировал в проект, но при запуске проекта выдает ошибку No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306/Park, в чем проблема не пойму mysql connector ставил разных версий и просто так и через maven результат один, в чем может быть проблема.
Если протестить соединение с БД из вкладки Database то проверка проходит, а когда запускаешь проект выдает ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить в maven

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.21</version>
</dependency>
```

и после этого обновить зависимости

p.s.: убедись, что обновлял зависимости, и что они скачались